# Audit failure with reasonable actions

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

**My first audit:**

I was making a review of an answer that seemed to be very good. I always like to check the question looking for other answers and I found that another user have the same answer. So I decided to flag the answer to notify that it was a duplicate, for this reason I failed the audit.

I think that this audit is inconsistent. If I go to the original question I cannot find the answer. Now I'm aware that it is an audit, but for an user that does not know that, that issue looks suspicious.

**Audit comes again:**

This time I had a short answer that needed some edit. Then I decided to make those edits. When I click on **edit** the system says that the post was deleted and cannot be edited. Since it was deleted I decided to click **no action** and I failed the audit because the post needed changes.

**Finally:**

I think that when a review is being audited the post that is given has too many inconsistencies:

- You cannot find the answer in the list of questions.
- If you try to edit it it may tell you that is was deleted.
- The audit fails when you click **flag**. Not waiting for the flag.

I know that there are other questions about audits. I just want to post this question as a reference of issues that I have faced when reviewing. I have failed two audits and I'm a very meticulous user when making reviews.

Comment: [Close vote review audit flawed - fails without casting vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179651/close-vote-review-audit-flawed-fails-without-casting-vote) and  [No markdown on review of Low Quality Posts, and Edit fails review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230376/no-markdown-on-review-of-low-quality-posts-and-edit-fails-review)

Comment: I think that in general, if the audit are here to identify robot-reviewers, there should be a system that lets you explain your case. I got a month of ban when I downvoted this: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4583777 because I thought it didn't show enough research. Turns out it is a very popular question. On the other hand, I don't mind not working for free for SO for a while...

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could earn a ban just by downvoting a question/answer for the wrong reasons...

Comment: @zyboxenterprises: Review bans are unrelated to post bans, which in turn is not the same as timed suspension. In the review queues (which you can access when you reach 500 reputation), you look over posts and check whether or not some action should be taken on them. In these queues, there are some audits which are selected by the system to make sure you're reviewing properly. If you fail too many of these, you can get review banned.

Comment: @Jigg, I don't think you can get banned for a single audit failure. Might be wrong though....

Comment: In my opinion, the audit questions need to be audited themselves. I too have gotten a failure for an answer to a question that was not only the correct, it was entirely appropriate for the site. The fact that the audit 'failed' makes me suspect that the system for deciding some or all of these audit is indeed a robot.

Comment: @ouflak you can get banned for one audit failure and the sanction raises each time it happens again, regardless of how many appropriate reviews you made in between.

Comment: @Jigg, I just wonder how that's possible considering that the system is supposed to look at a pattern before implementing a ban. Are you saying that some audit questions are weighted more heavily, even to such an extent that a single audit question could overwhelm a perfect record of dozens, or perhaps even hundreds, of successful audits?

Comment: @ouflak I don't think questions are weighted more than others, it's just cumulative. There was a thread on meta on the topic, can't find it any more.

Comment: @Jigg: Just as a data point, I have failed a few audits, and never got review banned yet. But I feel similarly to what you expressed in your first comment. If I ever get review banned for failing questionable audits, I won't lose any sleep over it. It's not like it's paying very well...