# High quality audit shows what appears to be a plagiarized answer

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

I've just failed an audit in /review for a very stupid reason. I was shown an answer, by a new user, to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559347/exc-bad-access-vs-segmentation-fault-are-both-same-practically). The answer was very good, but I decided to be sure, and opened the question in a new window. And I saw, that this question has an ABSOLUTELY IDENTICAL answer by a different user, and no answer by the user in the audit.

So I thought: "What the heck, the new user just made copy-pasta from a good answer, and then it was quickly deleted!" So I flagged this answer with the *other* reason and wrote **"That's an exact duplicate of different user's answer"**. And then clicked "Done".

Bang! I'm told, that

> This was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it
>   as-is or even upvoting.

And the new user's name *changes* to the nickname of the user whose post I thought was copy-pasted.

So, my questions are:

1. Is this normal behavior, that I'm not shown a true "new" user name?
2. If it's normal, then how do I find out whether I'm checking the original answer or a copy/paste? Because I've seen this several times outside of review, when a new user just copies someone else's answer.

Comment: Assuming you were in the Low Quality Post Queue, it wasn't a low quality post. Did you click 'Looks Good' or Recommend for Deletion? I am little confused as to how this played out

Comment: @staticx it was a [first post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5360272)

Comment: Thats just how review queues are intended to work: do the absolute minimum required by the queue and don't try to look around and find anything else possibly wrong with that post. Look at it as if it is in total isolation and the world around it doesn't exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Audit failure with reasonable actions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252830/audit-failure-with-reasonable-actions)

Comment: @Barett, yeah, that looks like the same issue. I did some search before posting question, but didn't find it. However, it doesn't have any answers at all.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely normal behaviour, to make sure you are paying attention to the *post*, not the user. Imagine a post by Jon Skeet being picked, for example.

If it *was* a copy-paste job, you'd see *both answers* when you followed the link.

Comment: If you don't have 10k rep, you can't see deleted answers. How do you distinguish between audits and deleted answers (possibly deleted between when you got the review and when you check the question)?

Comment: Then you judge *just the content*. If it isn't an audit, you said 'looks good' to something that is already gone (no loss), if it is an audit, audit passed!

Comment: Who is Jon Skeet?  :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, the most prolific and valued users of this site are people who like to dig into things and understand them.  They *will not* "just judge the content" if there's something else they think they can discover, and if something doesn't add up then it will smell fishy, at best.  So, thanks, but your advice is naive.  It only stands as the best advice because failing a single audit is not a big deal, but it's not a positive way in which to modify user behavior.

Comment: @Jason: Sure, but *in the context of reviews* with <10k points, those are your options.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I agree with Jason that this does not feel particularly constructive. I realize audits are tricky to get right, but certainly here it feels dysfunctional: the user invested more care than a normal reviewer and is punished for it.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: yet the conclusion was incorrect; they acted on incomplete evidence.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, if the primary goal of reviewing is to pass audits, then that's a good option.  If the goal of reviewing is to review well, then best to ignore the failed audit and move on, and trust that you won't run into so many badly designed audits that it actually impacts your ability to do it at all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what incomplete evidence? They acted on the evidence they were given. The fact that some of that evidence had been faked by the site tricked them into making a mistake. i.e. Stack Overflow lied to them and as a result they pressed the wrong button

Comment: @TimB: if this was their first ever review audit, *perhaps* you have a point. I can also see how they thought they had a copy, but that was a conclusion they jumped to themselves. Noone tricked them into thinking it was a plagiarised copy.

Comment: To be explicit, Stack Overflow claimed (contrary to reality) that the post was a new user's first post. Maybe the OP should not have believed that, but if it really was a new user's first post, then the OP did the right thing. And suppose a new user does start copying answers of others, and gets answers deleted because of it. What's preventing one of those answers from showing up as an audit?

Comment: The review queue works best if people aren't looking for audits so that they can pass them, otherwise you just have another way of gaming the system.  Not looking for audits, if you see something that doesn't add up (e.g. username mismatch of some sort), then the first conclusion must be that the user has gamed the system somehow, not that the system has obfuscated things.  So, flagging that post in some way would be the appropriate action.

Comment: @Jason: The audit system is designed at catching out those that are just clicking through the queue as fast as possible to get badges. Anyone that *pays attention* is welcome to detect that there is an audit going on.

Comment: You simply *cannot* defend the audit system as without flaws.  This is a flaw, simple as that.  There are many, and we see posts about them in Meta all the time.  I can understand the advice to just live with it and move on, I cannot understand the advice that you should act differently in some way just because of audits.  That's the last thing you want.  That's the whole point of how the SE system was designed, to encourage people to contribute in ways that they feel is constructive and let popular opinion sort out what's best.

Comment: @Jason: Who says I am defending the audit system? I am advocating a practical approach *because* there are flaws. The basic conclusion is that the OP conclusion about a copy was wrong, we can explain why it was wrong and how not to draw that conclusion in the future. In case of *real* plagiarism *the post would still be there*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, that is an *excellent* point.  This is an audit that **rewards** robo-reviewing, because only on taking your time does the answer appear suspect.

Comment: The practical approach is to ignore it, not to modify because of it.

Comment: @Jason: robo-reviewing is blindly picking the same option each time. That's why there are two different types of audits, to catch either.

Comment: Perhaps what I'm talking about, then, is not robo-reviewing but rather very low quality reviewing, the kind that takes only an extra 2 seconds to take in some superficial details about the post (such as length, is it formatted at all, read a random sentence in the middle to see if it's legible, and check what other reviewers have decided, if any) rather than trying to understand the context that the post is in, which is often important and thus why many reviewers will open the post in a separate window and, I assume, why SO provides the link in the first place.

Comment: @hvd: deletion is what would prevent it from showing in an audit.

Comment: Why not just not show the user name in the review at all?

Comment: @Jason: Don't get me wrong, I think users that do that, check the context, are *great*! And it's *those* users that should be aware of there being audits; they are *already doing the right thing*. If in doubt, *reload* the review page, if you want to make sure there is a genuine plagiarised copy. If it was deleted after you opened the review, the review will reflect that. If it was an audit, it is recorded as a *Skip* action.

Comment: I don't think there's much to be gained by continuing to hash this out, we probably don't honestly disagree that much. I'm content that the review system and the audit system are (as far as I understand) still receiving attention and improvements are being sought (and perfection is an unreasonable goal, anyway), the only reason I commented in the first place was to register my opinion that this does, in fact, represent a flaw of the current system. I feel at this point we're both clear on that :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Are you saying that when an answer is deleted, that answer is never used as an audit? I'm not sure about my own review history, but I have seen questions here on Meta about users who failed audits, when they thought the post looked good? Or do you mean that in the event of real plagiarism, posts will be deleted more destructively?

Comment: @hvd: When an answer is deleted, it *can* be used in an audit, but as a *negative*; in a *First Post* or *Late Answer* audit, deleted posts are used when the system has selected them as spam or low quality answers.

Comment: @hvd: In the case of real plagiarism, if the plagiarised post is picked as an audit, then that'd be a bad audit; I *think* the heuristics used to pick audits try to avoid those (usually a *great* answer, plagiarised, will have received upvotes too, it *usually* won't be a straight downvotes-only post, and it'll have *moderator attention - other* flags on it).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, that second comment is what I was missing. I think you're right, it wouldn't be likely to get picked as an audit.

Answer (score 16):

This could be really and truly solved by making "flag for plagiarism" an explicit option in First Post review, and count it as a *Pass* if the reviewer selects that on an anonymized high-quality post used for audit.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the exact same problem when I started doing reviews. In fact you will find a meta post very similar to yours discussing it.

All I can say is, you are not alone. It's stupid but it's the price we pay for reducing the number of robo reviewers...

Here's my post on it:
[High percentage of audits combined with audits failed for bad reasons putting me off reviewing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212355/high-percentage-of-audits-combined-with-audits-failed-for-bad-reasons-putting-me)

Answer (score 3):

Audits will deliberately fake most details to ensure you're judging as much by the post content, and as little by the metadata like author, score, accepted, etc as possible. This breaks somewhat in cases where that metadata is actually crucial, like here.

But there is a workaround that will never fail: in a new tab, **open the "link" link to the right of the post under review**. If it goes to a deleted question, this will be obvious; if a deleted answer, the link will not scroll down at all (unless you have 10k, in which case the deletion will again be obvious); otherwise, it will scroll to the top of *the answer being reviewed*, where you can then look around at the rest of the page to determine the actual situation — in particular, see if there's any actual duplication going on, or any other audit-related funny business.

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't seem to be the audit-process, but the review-process.

If the audit is faking metadata to ensure that people review based on post and not on metadata the obvious solution would be to **not include the metadata for any** review, i.e. just show the post itself.

Obviously that may slow down reviews, which is a downside. Hopefully the better quality of reviews will make up for that - but it has to be tested.

(The comment should likely be included; those are a bit problematic - sometimes they highlight an actual problem, sometimes they are wrong.)