# Questionable "Low Quality Post" review audit #2

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I hit [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9949363) as an audit in the LQP review queue today, and checked "Looks OK". By so doing, I failed the audit, and am now on a 2 day review hiatus.

I'd like that reversed, as the review is invalid. There is nothing in the post itself that would indicate it's Spam or otherwise offensive - but that is what the "stupid you" summary said.

If someone can explain why this post is a valid review, I'm all ears.

[Screenshot for <10k users.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evA2C.png)

Comment: Huh.  I'd like to know the interesting back story going on with that post.

Comment: I have no idea what I'm looking at, but staying here to hopefully find an explanation. (lowrepprobs)

Comment: Hmya, it is only ever "questionable" when somebody fails an audit.  To everybody else it is very obvious that the post was deleted two weeks ago.  Audits check if users pay attention and are not falling into a robo-reviewing habit.  Did you pay attention?  Did you pay attention when you failed all those other audits, enough of them to get blocked?  If you say "yes" then I'm all ears :)

Comment: Upvote for adding a screenshot for us plebs.

Comment: I think you failed the audit for using a white on black display.

Comment: A 2 day review hiatus isn't that bad, just accept it. IIRC you have to fail multiple audits to be benched...

Comment: @HansPassant: I really hope you're not dinging someone for not obsessively checking each and every review post in a new tab to see if it's an audit. Because quite frankly, that's an absurd level to have to go to to avoid audit failures. (Audits, for reasons that should be "very obvious", pretend posts aren't deleted, aren't accepted, aren't up- or down-voted, and so forth.)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297738/17034

Comment: @HansPassant - I wish there was an "I _don't_ understand" button, because the FEW audits I have failed have been stupid. I often think it's odd to see some post, and exit out to see what state it's in, and then do the WRONG thing to pass the audit. If that's what it takes, the audit system is BS, because it does not accomplish what it's supposed to.

Comment: @Mogsdad: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275272 Though 6-8 months are already gone.

Comment: @AndyHayden I don't necessarily agree that "a 2-day review hiatus isn't that bad".  There should be more people like the OP who take an active interest, not fewer. Making the experience suck less should be a priority.  I already abandoned reviewing a couple of times when it felt like the system was working against my attempts to be a good citizen.

Comment: @Deduplicator - Thanks for the pointer to that answer, it's described a rational process modification that could help mitigate the Meta traffic about odd audits.

Answer (score 6):

Well, it's a bit subtle, which isn't generally the hallmark of good audits, but not *quite* too much so.
No guarantee I would have caught it, myself.

But if you look at the post, it looks quite unlikely to be the answer to most questions: It only gives possible causes of an error, without any way to resolve them.
Actually, looking at the only (and prominent) link shows you that for some reason the poster copied the causes verbatim, but **not one word of the solution**.

And looking at the question confirms that it's just fishing for clicks, because the copied part *really* **doesn't answer *that* question**.

So you should have chosen to delete, and (just to be sure) followed that up with a SPAM-flag and a mod-flag to make sure nothing goes awry.

Comment: I would definitely have failed that audit, too. Audits which make you feel like the subject of a Turing test should simply not happen.  The review audit process seems to be failing in that respect (too).