# Allow edit on audit questions; defer pass/fail until final action/disposition

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I failed a review at [How to determine if a generic is an optional in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5561109).

I think I failed because I clicked *Edit*. I thought the question was pretty good, so I wanted to touch it up before clicking *I'm Done*. I wanted to touch it up because the first sentence was a bit awkward, and there were a few opportunities to provide formatting.

I'm pretty sure that the policy on Stack Overflow is to fix or salvage posts that are useful but could use improvement. If the question was in the queue because of bad grammar (or perhaps English As a Second Language), then that's something that should be fixed. So choosing to edit seems like a valid initial step.

I think the underlying issue here is the judgement is based on the first action of the person being audited (like *Edit* or *Comment*), and not the final action of the person being audited (like *Close*, *I'm Done* or *Skip*).

Is it possible to allow one to edit a question without being judged; and then base the audit results on the final action or disposition (like *I'm Done* or *Close*)? If its not possible, why does the site choose *not* to wait for final disposition to judge someone? (The last question seems to be harder to find an answer to).

---

There's a few variations on this in history, like [Close vote review audit flawed - fails without casting vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179651/close-vote-review-audit-flawed-fails-without-casting-vote) and [Review audit failed after just clicking “add comment”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment). This scenario is similar to [Audit failure with reasonable actions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252830/audit-failure-with-reasonable-actions), but the underlying question was not deleted.

Comment: The audit you link to says "Review audit passed"...

Comment: @hichris123 - that is weird. I definitely got the big ***STOP!*** message.