# Detecting punctuation link-spam in LQ-reviews / failed audit

Tags: support, review-audits

I just came across a [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12245279) in the low-quality queue that showed a badly formatted attempt of an answer with the comment:

> This post contains link-spam in punctation

Since I could not directly find any link, I hit edit to see the markup. As soon as I hit edit, I was told that I failed a review audit. I've had my share of questionable audits, but that one felt particularly weird.

*Did I correctly attempt to review this, or did I overlook a better & more efficient way to do the review?*

(I guess clicking the question and not seeing the answer would have been a giveway that it is an audit, but that's not the point.)

Comment: The cause: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647/213575

Comment: That's unfortunate but by design.  The system had no way to determine that your click of "edit" mean "view markdown" and not "I'm fixing this answer".

Comment: Wow.. I was not aware of this type of spam, so thanks for pointing this one out. FWIW, I would have done the exact same thing and been equally surprised when I failed the audit.

Comment: @Leigh I guess you missed the Meta post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320786

Comment: @ryanyuyu Only because the developers *chose* to declare audit failure as soon as you hit "edit" vs. waiting until you actually hit "Save Edits". That was a choice - a bad choice. That's patently unfair, given that reviewers can't otherwise view markdown to review it in the LQP queue.

Comment: There's a long history of this sort of BS declaring-audit-failure-before-action-is-actually-taken - see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269036/allow-edit-on-audit-questions-defer-pass-fail-until-final-action-disposition and all the questions it links to.

Comment: There's probably a userscript or two lying around allowing to see the markdown of posts everywhere. Otherwise, here's a new market!

Comment: @Laurel - Yep, I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I normally visit the post out of the queue by simply clicking the link at the right of the review screen and open the post in a second tab.

That gives me the opportunity to see everything in context, check the revision history or timeline. As you are not yet at 10K you would have found the post was deleted, which would have revealed what to choose.

The answer you were looking at contained this markup:

> ```
> This is called baste intent[.][1]
> ```
>
> private void startExplicitActivation() {
>
> ```
> Log.i(TAG,"Entered startExplicitActivation()");
>
> // TODO - Create a new intent to launch the ExplicitlyLoadedActivity class
> Intent explicitIntent = new Intent(ActivityLoaderActivity.this, ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.class);
>
>
>  // TODO - Start an Activity using that intent and the request code defined above
>     startActivityForResult(explicitIntent, 0);
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> [1]: https://twitter.com/[redacted]
> ```

See how the last period of the first line has a link.

The members of the SOCVR who respond to reports from the SmokeDetector leave a comment on spam posts to break the grace period, as explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321430/what-does-this-comment-kills-the-grace-period-mean)

Comment: I don't think anyone mentioned on my question (the one you linked to) that it was the SOCVR people who were doing this. I *knew* the comments were too similar to be coincidental, and this explains why.

Comment: @Laurel on Shog9 answer Brad responded with a comment that links to the transcript where we explained what had happened before and why we started doing that.